# How to implement Maven's unpack goal in case of Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jboss-arquillian

I'm learning Arquillian. I have read Getting Started Guide and now trying to run sample application with profile "arquillian-jbossas-managed", but I used Gradle instead of Maven and got the trouble. There is following plugin in sample's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jboss-as-dist</artifactId>
                        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I implement the same functionality in case of Gradle (I don't want to set JBOSS_HOME or copy distribution manually)?

P.S. Sorry if the question appeared too stupid - I'm novice in Gradle.
P.S.S. And sorry for my english.

Comment: What exactly does this do? Have you tried the [Arquillian Gradle plugin](https://github.com/aslakknutsen/arquillian-gradle-plugin)?

Comment: This goal unpacks artifact "jboss-as-dist" in target directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all this does is to resolve and unzip the JBoss distribution (as you suggested in your comment), then it would look like this in Gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() // or whatever repo is right
}

configurations {
    jboss
}

dependencies {
    jboss "org.jboss.as:jboss-as-dist:7.1.1.Final@zip"
}

task resolveJBoss(type: Copy) {
    destinationDir = file("jboss")
    from { zipTree(configurations.jboss.singleFile) }
}
```

I also encourage you to check out the [Arquillian Gradle plugin](https://github.com/aslakknutsen/arquillian-gradle-plugin).

Comment: Thank you for help. Unfortunately I cannot check your solution right now. I'll do it later. And I'll definitely try Arquillian plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have checked your solution and it works perfectly. The only thing I had to do is to set the dependency of task "test" from task "resolveJBoss": test.dependsOn resolveJBoss